# Vim: Mapping <C-+>

Tags: vim

Is there a way to map <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>) in vim? `:map <c-+>` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Don't forget that `-` and `Num -` are different keys, even though they produce the same `-` when pressed. (Also, VT100 numpads can be in "application" mode, where they actually produce escape sequences of their own.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot map it to that combinaton. Since Ctrl + doesn't in anything differ from just +, Vim has no way of recognizing it. Same goes for a lot of other combinations (for example, Ctrl-1 and such - they don't "send" anything back).

Comment: Yes; you can test whether something is map-able by going into insert mode and pressing `Ctrl-V` followed by the key you're interested in.  If something appropriate gets inserted, it should be map-able.  For example, enter `Ctrl-V Ctrl-+` does nothing, but `Ctrl-V Ctrl-P` gives `^P`

Comment: @Al - uuu, thanks! I knew there was some way to check it, but I never could remember how.